# AttributeError while NameError

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code that checks if the username exists in xcnfg.py, and if it doesn't it will ask the user for input.

This is my code:

```
import xcnfg
# INITIALIZE SETUP SEQUENCE
try:
    xcnfg.Username
except NameError:
    xcnfg.Username = input("What is your Username? ") 
    f = open( 'xcnfg.py', 'w' )
    f.write(xcnfg.Username)
    f.close()
# INITIALIZE MAIN PROGRAM
```

This is the error I get:

```
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    xcnfg.Username
AttributeError: module 'xcnfg' has no attribute 'Username'
```

Comment: catch AttributeError instead of NameError.

Answer (score 1):

Question Answered by mechanical_meat:

> catch AttributeError instead of NameError.